# Define simple type such as xsd:string in a new namespace?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

This should be straight forward but everywhere I look it seems to have information only about complex types.

Let's say that I have defined a namespace `xmlns:address="http://...."`. Now from what I have read it seams like I could do the following: `<xsd:element name="street" type="address:sAdd"/>` and then define the complex type `<xsd:complexType name="sAdd">`.

However, I cannot find what happens in the case of a non complex type like a `xsd:string`. My guess would be something like `<xsd:element name="street" type="address:xsd:string"/>`.

Can you please verify my answer or let me know about the correct way of doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, namespace prefixes cannot be cascaded:  `address:xsd:string` is not a well-formed [QName](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-QName).

An `xsd:string` will be the same in all namespaces.  This is as it should be.

If you want *your* string to vary from `xsd:string`, define a type for your string based on `xsd:string`, and place it in a namespace (or not) per your design preferences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:mst="http://www.example.com/MyStringType"
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/MyStringType">

  <xs:element name="root" type="mst:MyStringType"/>

  <xs:simpleType name="MyStringType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="256" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clears things up. In the case that I got under the same xml 2 different `name` elements for example `<human><name>jonh</name></human> <fruit><f:name>apple</f:name></fruit>` how do I make the distinction between them when defining a schema?

Comment: You'll want to differentiate the `name` elements themselves by namespaces, not strings in general.  For example, in the `http://example.com/People` namespace, `name` might be of an enumeration that includes "john", "mary", etc, while in the `http://example.com/Fruit` namespace, `name` might be of an enumeration that includes "apple", "pear", etc.

Comment: can you give a short example taking into account my above example. I don't really see what you mean. I'm quite new to Schemas and I think I am missing some vital points. Thank you _ EDIT: you did edit as I was typing that. So in other words, you're saying that elements that have types like `string` cannot have a namespace. As what your example shows is that the elements must be of a different data type

Comment: I thought I did give you an example.   If I've answered your question on namespaces and simple types, perhaps you might [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215)  this answer and ask a new question detailing your further concerns?  Thank you.

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example of usage of this new string type?

Comment: @Cullub: Use of the new string type in the XSD is already illustrated.  Use in an XML document: `<root xmlns="http://www.example.com/MyStringType">This string must be 256 characters or less in length.</root>`