# XML schema: How to change the maxLength of all strings in document

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I want to set the schema-wide `maxLength` value of `xsd:string` in one place and have it apply anywhere `xsd:string` is used.  I want to limit any and all strings to 50 characters, for example.

I know I can do this...

```
<xsd:simpleType name="MaxLen50">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
...
<xsd:element name="Foo" type="MaxLen50" />
<xsd:element name="Bar" type="MaxLen50" />
<xsd:element name="Baz" type="MaxLen50" />
```

...but the problem is that I would have to go to every string in the XSD and change it from `xsd:string` to `MaxLen50`.  I just want to set the default for `xsd:string` and have it apply to all elements with `type="xsd:string"`

Comment: Simply use a _find-replace_ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing built-in and user-defined types.

Built-in/primitive types are meant to be the basic building blocks used to create user-defined types.  You don't change the built-in types directly.

You have the right idea in defining a `xsd:simpleType` as a `xsd:restriction` of `xsd:string` and using that user-defined type where needed.  Just don't bake the length into the name of the type.  (Further, type names should be domain-based, not implementation-based.)  That way you'll have a single place to adjust the `50` as requested.

Finally, note that a maintenance issue more worthy of your attention concerns the versioning of the XSD wrt existing documents, code, APIs, etc should you ever actually want to change that `50` in a published XSD.

Comment: thanks.  I would be grateful to see how this would be written in my schema document (with a namespace prefix if possible...been trying and searching for more than an hour without success...even bumped into your other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34568983/442665).  I put this in my root node: `xmlns:hod="http://hod.com/2019/XMLSchema"` (below similar :xsd and :xs ones).  Then this child of root: `<xsd:simpleType name="hod:string"><xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"><xsd:maxLength value="50"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType>` Then `type="hod:string"` in element. IDE: "can't resolve type."

Comment: I'd recommend a new ***question*** rather than a *comment* for your follow-up so you can format the code and provide a nice [mcve].  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that defining a global limit of 50 characters on all strings is a pretty bad design choice. It takes one back to the days of punched cards.

There is no way for a user to change the semantics of built-in types like xs:string. You need to define a subtype, as you have suggested. And if you want to use the same subtype of xs:string everywhere, you are going to have to make the change everywhere. There are all sorts of ways you can automate the process of doing the global replace, but a global replace it will have to be.